# Toggle RGB Background Color

Tags: javascript, html, css, rgb, innerhtml

I'm trying to be able to toggle the background color from RGB to a solid color. I am using Change inner HTML to change the background color this is what I have however I'm having trouble getting it to work, I'm not sure what the problem is I have never done change inner HTML so I'm Kind of a beginner at this.

This is what I have so far
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body oncontextmenu="return false" onkeydown="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">
  <div id="toggle">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <button onclick="tog()">Toggle</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And this is what I have for css

```
.wrapper {
  margin:0px;
  height: 200%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(
    124deg,
    #ff2400,
    #e81d1d,
    #e8b71d,
    #e3e81d,
    #1de840,
    #1ddde8,
    #2b1de8,
    #dd00f3,
    #dd00f3
  );
  background-size: 1800% 1800%;

  -webkit-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
  -z-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
  animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
}
@keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
}
```

This is the javascript that I have so far

```
let rgb;

function tog(){
 if(rgb = <div class="wrapper">
    <button onclick="tog()">Toggle</button>
   </div>){
 toggle.innerHTML = <button onclick="tog()">Toggle</button>;
 }else{
 toggle.innerHTML = <div class="wrapper">
    <button onclick="tog()">Toggle</button>
   </div>;
}
}
```

Comment: Your function `tog()` isn't using correct javascript syntax. You are mixing regular html with it. If you open the browser console and type `tog` you will see that it is undefined because of the syntax errors.

Comment: Furthermore can you better describe this: *I'm trying to be able to toggle the background color from RGB to a solid color*. Which element are you trying to change the background color? The whole page?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the solid color we want is green.So let's create a class called `solid-color` :

```
.solid-color{
  background: green;
}
```

Your syntax in JavaScript is wrong

Hope the following code will help you achieve your goal:

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

function tog() {
  if (wrapper.classList.contains('solid-color')) {
    wrapper.classList.remove('solid-color');
  } else {
    wrapper.classList.add('solid-color');
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 200%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient( 124deg, #ff2400, #e81d1d, #e8b71d, #e3e81d, #1de840, #1ddde8, #2b1de8, #dd00f3, #dd00f3);
  background-size: 1800% 1800%;
  -webkit-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
  -z-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
  animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
}

.solid-color {
  background: green;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
}

@keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="toggle">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button onclick="tog()">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```